Zenodo access ["metadata"]["description"]
this piece of code returns records from zenodo with no problem
import requests
import json

records_api_url = 'https://zenodo.org/api/records'
search_query = 'grants.acronym:DIGITAF AND resource_type.type:publication'
res = requests.get(records_api_url, params={'q': search_query, 'size': 10000})
for i in res.json()["hits"]["hits"]:
    print(i["metadata"], "\n" )


returning about 20 hits (dictionaries), one of them, as example here:
{
    "title": "Agroforestry & the Framework for Certification of Carbon Removals",
    "doi": "10.5281/zenodo.7828353",
    "publication_date": "2022-12-31",
    "description": "<p>Policy Briefing #20 welcomes the draft CRCF, and its initial proposals for robust certification of carbon removals including a) quality criteria, b) verification and certification, c) functioning of certification schemes.&nbsp; However we feel that rigorous certification is only needed for a subset of specialised
 carbon farming schemes.&nbsp; There is much more to be done, in the near term, to meet the aspirational target of the December 2021 &ldquo;Sustainable Carbon Cycles Communication&rdquo; that &ldquo;by 2028 every land manager should have access to verified emission and removal data&rdquo;.&nbsp; EURAF believes that high quality emissions estimates by Member States (IPCC Tier 3) should be combined with detailed wall-to-wall representation of land use (IPCC Approach 3), and results should be available open source to farmers and foresters.&nbsp; High-resolution databases of net emissions across the forestry and agricultural sectors will facilitate a target of net zero emissions in the integrated land sector by 2035. These improvements by MS should proceed in parallel with amendment and ratification of the CRCF.</p>",
    "access_right": "open",
    "creators": [
        {
            "name": "LAWSON, Gerry",
            "affiliation": "EURAF",
            "orcid": "0000-0002-1395-3092"
        }
    ],
    "keywords": [
        "carbon farming",
        "agroforestry",
        "DigitAF"
    ],
    "version": "1",
    "resource_type": {
        "title": "Working paper",
        "type": "publication",
        "subtype": "workingpaper"
    },
    "license": {
        "id": "cc-by-4.0"
    },
    "grants": [
        {
            "code": "101059794",
            "internal_id": "10.13039/501100000780: : 101059794",
            "funder": {
                "name": "European Commission",
                "doi": "10.13039/501100000780",
                "acronym": "EC"
            },
            "title": "DIGItal Tools to help AgroForestry meet climate, biodiversity and farming sustainability goals: linking field and cloud",
            "acronym": "DIGITAF",
            "program": "HE",
            "url": "https: //cordis.europa.eu/projects/101059794"
        }
    ],
    "communities": [
        {
            "id": "euraf"
        },
        {
            "id": "eu"
        }
    ],
    "relations": {
        "version": [
            {
                "index": 0,
                "is_last": True,
                "parent": {
                    "pid_type": "recid",
                    "pid_value": "7828352"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "notes": "EURAF Policy Briefing #20"
}

I have no problem accessing the title from this dict with
print(i["metadata"]["title"], "\n" )

However, when trying accessing the description with
print(i["metadata"]["description"], "\n" )

returns a "KeyError: 'description'" which is puzzling me. What am I missing?
print(i["metadata"]["title"] # works fine
print(i["metadata"]["doi"] # works fine
print(i["metadata"]["publication_date"] # works fine

print(i["metadata"]["description"] # DOES NOT WORK -> triggers a KeyError: 'description'


Are you aware there is an unterminated string caused by a newline character in your input (between specialised and carbon)?

Apparently not every one of the dictionaries has the "description" key.

Try instead print(i["metadata"].get("description", "no description available"))

Thanks everyone! there is one item that has no description indeed... @larsks tip does the job!

Thanks to @mkrieger and @larsks the problem can be turned around by getting the key value, when there is actually the key (So this is actually a duplicate from a "normal key error" question). Anyway here's the piece with getting the key value when the key exists:
import requests
import json

records_api_url = 'https://zenodo.org/api/records'
search_query = 'grants.acronym:DIGITAF AND resource_type.type:publication'
res = requests.get(records_api_url, params={'q': search_query, 'size': 10000})
for i in res.json()["hits"]["hits"]:
    print(i["metadata"].get("description", "no description available"))

